# Reset fid in GeoPackage table

Tags: geopackage

Is it possible to reset the fid of my GeoPackage table so it begins with value '1' again after clearing the table?

The background is: I have a more or less complex table I would like to "reuse" in another project. So I copied and cleared it, but if I then and add a new feature, the fid starts not with '1' - It continuous with the last fid + 1.

Is there a possibility to reset the fid so that it starts with '1'?

Comment: This is really just a TRUNCATE TABLE question with respect to SQLite, which is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601697/sqlite-reset-primary-key-field

Comment: Fid values have no meaning so it doesn't matter

Comment: I use the fid as primary-key in my purpose

Comment: I would consider to use a normal unique attribute for a feature ID if it is also used as a foreign key constrains and perhaps outside the GeoPackage. Using FID as a primary key is what db architect probably prefers but for example a GDAL user needs to know a bunch of tricks if FIDs need to be translated between datasources and to other formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment the question is about resetting the database sequence but I would like to add that the GeoPackage standard is written so that it does not allow your plan. Standard defines that the primary key columns are created with this SQL

```
CREATE TABLE sample_feature_table (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ...
```

The SQLite documentation explains what this means in https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that
> changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse
> of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the
> purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
> previously deleted rows.

It may be safe to do the update `SEQ=0`. I did a simple test by resetting the sequence of a non-empty GeoPackage table and inserting a new row. SQLite did not corrupt the database by using FID=1 but it used FID=max(FID)+1 and set that value also into the sequence.

But even the workflow copy table - truncate - update sequence may work I am not sure if it makes sense. If you will delete all the data anyway then why don't you just create a new empty table with the same schema than the original? You can find the SQL that you need with

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'name_of_your_table';
```

Is the table that you want to copy a spatial GeoPackage table? How do you copy the required triggers and make the inserts into the metadata tables for making the new table as a usable GeoPackage table?